# Needed helpful hand with sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hello I've been trying to write query that shows all sum of sales month by month. Data also should be grouped by country and category.

Each country has to present all data in all categories even the data don't exists. I know that I probably need cross join and at least one left join, but for few hours I can't figure out how to do it.

Below I attach tables and desired result to help understand.

Table Product

```
ProductId | Name   | CountryId | CategoryId
------------------------------------------
    4     |  Ax    |     4     |     3
    5     |  Ball  |     5     |     4
```

Table Category

```
CategoryId | Name
-----------------
    3      | Detail
    4      | Hurt
```

Table Country

```
CountryId | CountryName
-----------------------
    4     | Germany
    5     | Sweden
```

Table SaleYear

```
SaleYearId | Year | ProductId
-----------------------------
      1    | 2018 |    4
      2    | 2018 |    5
```

Table Sale

```
SaleId | SaleYearId | Month1 | Month2 | Month3 | Month4
   1   |     1      |   100  | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
   2   |     2      |   NULL | 500    | NULL   | NULL
```

Desired result should looks like:

```
CountryId | CategoryId | Year | Month1 | Month2 | Month3 | Month4
    4     |      3     | 2018 | 100    | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
    4     |      4     | NULL | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
    5     |      3     | NULL | NULL   | NULL   | NULL   | NULL
    5     |      4     | 2018 | NULL   | 500    | NULL   | NULL
```

DDL and SAMPLE DATA: http://rextester.com/HHN19990

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: I'm not understanding how you could get year 2018 for data that does not exist?  For example, your 2nd result, where does that year come from since it would need to use an outer join and no records would match for countryid 4 and categoryid 4?

Comment: My fault, in 2nd result year of course should be null.I corrected my post.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could turn that sample into ddl (create table statements) and dml (insert statements). The first thing somebody has to do is make that something useful before we can even start working on the problem. But I am a bit nervous about columns like Month1, Month2. That looks a lot like repeating groups which violates 1NF and will make this far more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Of course, I will do it next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use `cross join` with multiple `outer joins`:

```
select c.countryid, 
    cat.categoryid,
    sy.year,
    s.month1, 
    s.month2, 
    s.month3, 
    s.month4
from country c cross join category cat
    left join product p on c.countryid = p.countryid and cat.categoryid = p.categoryid
    left join saleyear sy on p.productid = sy.productid
    left join sale s on sy.saleyearid = s.saleyearid
```

- [Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/EFJSC96034)

This will create a `cartesian product` of all the results in the `category` and `country` tables.  Your example has 2 in each - 2*2 = 4 results.  If however you had 5 in each, you'd receive 25 results.

Comment: This is what I need, since I said I need summed data, I let myself to correct your answer:

select c.countryid, 
 cat.categoryid,
 sy.year,
   SUM(s.month1), 
 SUM(s.month2), 
 SUM(s.month3), 
 SUM(s.month4)
from country c cross join category cat
 left join product p on c.countryid = p.countryid and cat.categoryid = p.categoryid
 left join saleyear sy on p.productid = sy.productid
 left join sale s on sy.saleyearid = s.saleyearid
    group by c.countryid, cat.categoryid, sy.year

Comment: @tylkonachwile sorry, didn't see your comment about summing.  glad you got it working with this though!